# NetSuite formula to show quantity ordred on first order

Tags: netsuite, saved-searches

We have a saved search in place that displays date of first order and last order by customer & item within a given date range. For example - Looking at sales for May 2022 - today, it shows the item, the customer, the date they first ordered the item, and the date they last ordered the item.

I am now also trying to incorporate the quantity ordered on the first order.

[crietera](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seF0G.png)
[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8cig.png)

I've tried the following, but keep getting an invalid expression. Can anyone advise on how I might be able to display the qty on the date of the first order?

```
MIN(CASE WHEN {custbody_reporting_ship_date} THEN {quantity} END)
```

and

```
CASE WHEN (MIN({custbody_reporting_ship_date})THEN  {quantity} END)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this can't be achieved in saved search via simple formula. You may want to try below, what I will do is try to record the first and last order id in the customer record, then from customer saved search you can source from these order fields to the order details.

1. Create 2 custom entity fields applied to customer
   first order id => Type:List/Record => List/Record:Transaction
   last order id => Type:List/Record => List/Record:Transaction
2. Create 1 saved search to get the first order id per customer
   Similar to the one that you created, the result field just need the customer internal id and min(document number) and filter need to add customer.internal id
3. Create 1 saved search to get the last order id per customer
   Similar to the one that you created, the result field just need the customer internal id and max(document number) and filter need to add customer.internal id
4. Create 2 scheduled workflows, to update the first order id and last order id fields in respective customer record.
5. Create your first and last order customer Saved Searches using the 2 custom fields to source for the order details.

Not sure if this help.